# Xamarin Forms Await/Async Task on Main Thread

Tags: xamarin.forms, async-await

I am downloading images from my app to phone gallery for both iOS and android successfully. Below is my code:

```
public void DownloadImages_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)

        {

            CarDetailLoader.IsVisible = true;
            CarDetailLoader.IsRunning = true;

            foreach (var imgurl in car.CarImages)
            {
                var webClient = new WebClient();
                byte[] imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(imgurl);

                DependencyService.Get<IMediaServices>().SaveImageFromByte(imageBytes, "DINImage");
            }

            CarDetailLoader.IsVisible = false;
            CarDetailLoader.IsRunning = false;
        }
```

However, the ActivityLoader doesn't work when this method runs, even though it takes a few seconds. I tried using some:

Task.Run(() => )

methods that I read online, however,

"SaveImageFromByte()" method can only run on the main thread.

So how do I approach this issue?

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Task.Run()` to await the Task and use [Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms) to run method in Main thread, here is an example:

```
  public async void DownloadImages_Clicked()

    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            CarDetailLoader.IsVisible = true;
            CarDetailLoader.IsRunning = true;
        });


        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i< 3;i++)
            {

                //var webClient = new WebClient();
                //byte[] imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData((string)imgurl);
               
                Console.WriteLine("before delay");

                await Task.Delay(3000);

                Console.WriteLine("after delay");

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    //DependencyService.Get<IMediaServices>().SaveImageFromByte(imageBytes, "DINImage");
                    Console.WriteLine("BeginInvokeOnMainThread");
                });         
            }
        });


        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            CarDetailLoader.IsVisible = false;
            CarDetailLoader.IsRunning = false;
        });

    }
```