# Why can't my xamarin app recieve data from my API call?

Tags: api, xamarin.forms, localhost

Im new to connecting an API to my xamarin app.

When I try to call the API visual studio & the app do not give a response.
Visual studio keeps running but nothing happens.

I've changed the firewall settings, and set my IP adres in all the desired places. Still not luck.
If I go to my API using swager or postman and I just the same Uri as I want to pass trough with my app I get the correct response.
What could be the reason for this?

my code:

Material service:

```
   private readonly string _baseUri;
        public APIMaterialService()
        {
            _baseUri = "https://192.168.1.9:5001/api";
        }

        public async Task<Material> GetById(Guid id)
        {
            return await WebApiClient
               .GetApiResult<Material>($"{_baseUri}/Materials/{id}");
        }
```

WebApiClient:

```
 public class WebApiClient
    {
        private static HttpClientHandler ClientHandler()
        {
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
#if DEBUG
            //allow connecting to untrusted certificates when running a DEBUG assembly
            httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
#endif
            return httpClientHandler;
        }

        private static JsonMediaTypeFormatter GetJsonFormatter()
        {
            var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
           
            formatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            return formatter;
        }

        public async static Task<T> GetApiResult<T>(string uri)
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(ClientHandler()))
            {

//Gets stuck finding the response

                string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
               
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response, GetJsonFormatter().SerializerSettings);
            }
        }
```

I'll also add some images of the postman and swager response:
[image]

[image]

This is the code fo my controller.
return OK (material) shows me the data retrieved from the API

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetMaterialByPartOfMaterialNumberOP(string partOfMaterialNumber)
        {
            var material = await _materialService.GetMaterialListbyPartOfMaterialNumber(partOfMaterialNumber);


            return Ok(material);
        }
```

Comment: use the browser on the device/emulator to verify that your service endpoint is reachable.  If you are using a local dev webserver, be sure that it is configured to accept remote requests.  99% of the time these problems are due to connectivity

Comment: the endpoint is reachable through postman.
I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "be sure that is configured to accept remote requests"

Comment: I didn't ask if Postman could reach it.  Postman runs on your desktop, which is a completely different environment with different restrictions than a mobile device/emulator.  That's why you need to test connectivity from the device.  And the built in web server in VS does not accept requests from remote machines by default.  You have to configure it to allow that.

Comment: I did multiple configurations:
in the startup and launch file of the API, in my UWP settings, In my anroid manifest, in my app.xaml.cs. In my webapiclient service, all to make sure it connects with the IP address

Did some further testing. and debugged in my controller, the data is returned from the API it self, but then it does nothing further in my materialservice of webapiclientservice

Comment: None of that answers my question.  If you open the browser on the device/emulator and try to connect to `https://192.168.1.9:5001/api` do you get a response?

Comment: Yes, i get a response

Comment: if you call the actual endpoint in the browsers do you get a json response?  Have you debugged `HttpClientHandler` to verify it is getting called?  If you put a breakpoint in the server code (or check the logs) is it receiving the response from the client?

Comment: *" debugged in my controller, the data is returned from the API itself,"* - are you saying that you do see the data at some point in your app code? If so, do you show that code? But then `string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);` never returns? Possibly a deadlock. My vague thought is to use `Task.Run(async() => ` at some point in code, to make sure you aren't on MainThread. Then once you have the response, before doing any calls that affect UI `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() => ...` to get back to MainThread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62987810/199364

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I will try this thank you.
I have added the code of my controller to the original post.
I retrieve the data from the API, but you are right ```string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri) ```never returns any data.

I'm not sure what ou mean with the task.Run async but I will check the code later today.

Comment: @Jason I have done so. The data is being called, but never returns. VS just stops working

Comment: I don't know what else to suggest.  In my experience these sorts of problems are almost always due to connectivity.  Can you deploy your service to a public host?  Or even deploy a static json file on a public host to simulate your service?  That would be my next step

Comment: @Jason tried that as well.. Does not seem to work.. Thanks again anyway for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

The symptom you have (stuck on result from calling a method of HttpClient class) suggests a deadlock.

I believe the deadlock happens if you create multiple instances of HttpClient.

Doc [HttpClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) says:

> // HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use. See Remarks.

And shows this code:

```cs
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

HOWEVER a deadlock would only happen the SECOND time your code does `new HttpClient`. And `using ... new HttpClient` *should* protect you, at least in simple situations.

Here are ways there might be TWO HttpClients active:

- Is it possible that `GetApiResult` gets called A SECOND TIME, before the first one finishes?
- Does your app do `new HttpClient` ELSEWHERE?

Here is what the technique might look like in your app:

```cs
public class WebApiClient
{
    static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(ClientHandler());

    public async static Task<T> GetApiResult<T>(string uri)
    {
        string response = await _client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response, GetJsonFormatter().SerializerSettings);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I had a two-hour debug session with my teacher tonight.
The problem seemed to be VS-related.. We tried and tried for 2 hours, and without changing something all of a sudden it worked.
Thanks for all the tips and help!